# easiest way to debug hibernate XML config?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

what is the easiest way to troubleshoot a hibernate xml configuration?

I'd love to see helpful error messages such as what a compiler generates when compiling java, with a line number at least.  Right now all I see is:

```
Error Creating SessionFactory: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document
```

Comment: can you share your hibernate.cfg.xml file? You must have messed up somewhere in the file. There is no way apart from looking into the file.

Comment: Well I'm not asking for help on my particular xml file, because there are a lot of xml files I need to configure.  What I'm asking is:  is there a way or trick or tool that can validate my xml file, to give me more descriptive error messages that "could not parse mapping document".

Comment: What if your java compiler only gave an error "could not compile program".  That wouldn't be very helpful so instead the compiler says something like "Syntax error on line 12".   How can I see line numbers (and possibly message) when the xml configuration file is parsed to determine the mapping?

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't any such utility available. You need to rely on the exception message which hibernate throws in case of mis-configuration. Can you share the code and your xml file so that we can look what exactly you are doing.

Comment: @user3302169 An XML editor / validator should be enough to check for error messages indicating syntactic errors. All other errors usually create a more specific message. And you should always check for the `Caused by` lines - sometimes the specific error message is hidden somewhere down the stacktrace.